# Is there any way to use the "all" or the "any" function with two for loops in python

Tags: python

I am writing some python code (it really doesn't matter what I'm writing) and got to a situation that I needed to check if some condition is for a specific index to all of the lists inside a two dimensional list. So of course I know the `all()` function but that kind of things requires two for loops for example:

```
for i in range(len(list_name)):
    if all(small_list[i] % 2 == 0 for small_list in list_name):
        # do something
```

My question is if is there any way to do something that requires two loops in an `all` or an `any` without writing one of the loops outside of the all function?

Comment: you want a nested list comphrension?

Answer (score 2):

So what you're saying is you need to check `all()` but for every element of a 2D list. Would simple nested `all()`s work?

```
if all(all(element % 2 == 0 for element in small_list) 
       for small_list in list_name):
```

Or, mirroring your given code more closely,

```
if all(all(small_list[i] % 2 == 0 for small_list in list_name) for i in range(len(list_name)))
```

---

As pointed out by @chepner in a comment, you actually don't need the second `all` - you can put multiple clauses in a comprehension like so:

```
if all(small_list[i] % 2 == 0 
       for small_list in list_name 
       for i in range(len(list_name))):
```

Comment: `and` is associative, so you only need one `all`: `all(x % 2 == 0 for small_list in list_name for x in small_list)`.

Comment: Just one question, are you using generator expressions internally this way?

Comment: @BlueRineS Yes, each argument to `all` is a generator expression, so that you don't have to generate the entire list of Booleans before `all` starts checking them.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited my answer to include that detail

Answer (score 1):

> ...check if some condition is [true] for a **specific index** to **all of the lists** inside a two dimensional list...

Judging from what you wrote, we don't actually need two `for` loops at all.

```
specific_index = 3
if all(small_list[specific_index] % 2 == 0 for small_list in list_name):
    doSomething()
```

Replace `specific_index` with the magic number of your choice.